# Read Impala tables and column names from Spark job

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, impala

I have tables in different impala data bases, stored as parquet files, structured as below. I'm trying to figure out a good way to scan all the table names and column names, under all databases, from there I hope to check if the table or column names contain certain values, if so I'd like to read the values etc.

I understand that there are impala query like `describe database.tablename`, but with all the other processing, I'd like to do this in a spark job. Could some one please help to shed some light on this? Many thanks.

```
database1.tableOne
database1.tableTwo
database2.tableThree
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to impala with jdbc data frame of spark with .query() option containing describe table. And then reading the dataframe returning from jdbc operator gives the column information.